# Limit review by e-mail

Tags: review

I have a site with reviews. I am reviewing companies and not products. So instead of products, I have companies create in Woocommerce. The problem is my users can review a company unlimited times. Only option in wordpress is to limit reviews by verified customers but since there is no puchace, I cannot use that function. How do I limit a user to only review a company (product) 1 time. (Can review other products but again only 1 time)

Answer (score 0):

This question should really be directed to the Woocommerce support but it doesn't really sound like Woocommerce is the right solution here.

Create a plugin and in the plugin, create a custom post type called companies. Using something like https://generatewp.com/post-type/ will help you get started quickly.
Then you want to look at implementing your own reviewing system or plugin and you will be able to have complete control.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. I have a woking site here: https://joblogger.dk/firma/a-tex-a-s/   In the first tab I have the review system that allows to review an unlimited times. In the second tab I have a review system that checks if the mail has already been used to review tha company. I need a combination of the 2 since the review system in tab 2 is very limited in functionallity.